# Unable to add a String to an ArrayList: "misplaced construct(s)"

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am trying to add a string to an ArrayList in Java, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
List food_names = new ArrayList();

food_names.add("pizza");
```

Why do I get these errors:

> - Syntax error on token ""pizza"", delete      this token
> - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced      construct(s)

Comment: What language? ArrayList exists in at least Java and .NET. It does not look like .NET errors though.

Comment: What language are you using? Java?

Comment: did you copy and paste the code? eg I'm wondering if you're using the wrong quotes like you may get from pasting from MS Word

Comment: Nope. Typing them in manually

Comment: Is this the exact code or is there anything in between? Also, you might want to use `List<String> food_names = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the code into the Question (not as a comment!), and include more code for context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `food_names.add("pizza")` in function, for example:

```
public void AddFood()
{
  food_names.add("pizza");
}
```

Hope helps

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.  I'm not used to such strict languages.  I kinda wish the compiler gave more useful error messages.

Comment: @mellowg - learn to live with it.  The compiler cannot read your mind to figure out what you were *really* trying to do.  (The same thing applies to a non-strict language ... with the added bonus that the compiler is more likely to decide on a meaning for your code that is not what you thought you'd written.)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but please stick to the widespread Java conventions - use a lowercase character as first method name character. See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch07_01.htm

Answer (score 5):

why don't you use List Generics List interface.

```
 List<String> food_names = new ArrayList<String>();

food_names.add("pizza");
```

This shouldn't give any error.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that those statements are at the top level of a class.  The first one is OK there, but the second one can only be inside a code block; e.g. a method or constructor body.  See @tomasBull's answer for an example of where you can do that.

The compiler is trying to parse `food_names.add("pizza");` as a declaration, and is getting thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution

```
food_names.add(new String("pizza"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're initializing the ArrayList correctly. Try

```
ArrayList<String> food_names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also double check you've imported ArrayList. Or try removing the quotation marks around pizza.
Disclaimer: I'm probably wrong but I'm laying in bed typing this from my phone, haha. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the browser on my phone was giving me issues.

Comment: Found you, Rahul Phulore  . . . . :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Example 
{

//**Do not place it here.**
List food_names = new ArrayList();
food_names.add("pizza");

 public static void main(String[] args)
{

//**You should place it here**
List food_names = new ArrayList();
food_names.add("pizza");

}


}
```