# Java: Adding new element to List<String>

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public void parseAttribs(String attribs){

   //attribs is a comma separated list
   //we are making a List from attribs by splitting the string at the commas

   List<String> attributes = Arrays.asList(attribs.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

   //when I try to add an element to the attributes List if fails
   attributes.add("an element");
```

I've found this [Unable to add a String to an ArrayList: "misplaced construct(s)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055936/how-can-i-add-a-string-to-an-arraylist-in-java) and tried to create a sub-class but I had to pass the List to the subclass as well and it still didn't work.

Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks Reimeus and Rangi Lin. It works with your suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a *fixed-size*`List`. You could use

```
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(...)))
```

This will give you a `List` where elements *can* be added.

Answer (score 6):

This code will not works because the list returned by `Arrays.asList()` is an immutable list.

You can construct from an ArrayList constructor to make it works.

```
List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(attribs.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
```