# Can't add to an ArrayList "misplaced construct(s)"

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a simple arraylist set up, but I can't seem to add objects to it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Inventory {

ArrayList inventory = new ArrayList();

String item1 = "Sword";
String item2 = "Potion";
String item3 = "Shield";

inventory.add(item1);
inventory.add(item2);
inventory.add(item3);
}
```

There are two errors, one at the dot between inventory and add, and one at the variable names between the brackets, being

```
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

and

```
Syntax error on token "item1", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: This should be written inside a method.

Comment: Also, using raw arraylist might not be the best idea, rather use ArrayList<String>

Comment: You could also write `Arrays.asList("Sword", "Potion", "Shield");`

Comment: Down-vote canceled by an up-vote. I'm not sure why anyone would down-vote someone because they weren't born knowing Java. This is a perfectly valid question (although I can see it being closed for being a duplicate since it has been asked *many* times on this site).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree. +1 also from me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Agreed.

Comment: @AdamMiszczak The existing answers are indeed correct for your problem, its worth noting however that using `ArrayLists` in their generic form can be a little unpleasent (they contain `Objects` which you can cast to `String` if you know they are `Strings`, but it could contain any object), a more pleasent way to use them can be to declare what kind of object they contain, so `ArrayList<String> inventory =new ArrayList<String>();`. Now you can only put `Strings` in the arraylist and `get()` methods will directly return `strings`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a String to an ArrayList in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055936/how-can-i-add-a-string-to-an-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why your code does not work is that you tried to write code in the class body. Executable statements should be written in static initializers, methods or constructors (as I did in the example below).

Try this:

```
public class Inventory {

    private List inventory = new ArrayList();

    public Inventory() {

        String item1 = "Sword";
        String item2 = "Potion";
        String item3 = "Shield";

        inventory.add(item1);
        inventory.add(item2);
        inventory.add(item3);
    }
}
```

I defined the class member `inventory` in the class body and initialized it in-place (`= new ArrayList();`). No compiler error there because declarations are allowed in class body. The rest of the code I put into the constructor that will initialize `inventory` with values. I could have put it in a method, but I chose the constructor because its usual role is to initialize class members.

Comment: You might want to explain beside showing a working code. Explain it and my neutral vote will become +1.

Comment: This worked, thanks! But like others said, can you please explain why this works?

Comment: 1+ for the improved answer.

Comment: I would certainly add a little about why you should use `List` rather than `ArrayList` and why `List<String>` would be the optimal declaration.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, you cannot have executable statements, such as invocations of the `add` method, outside a definition of a method or a constructor. Declarations are OK, but executable statements are not.

You can add these items to a named constructor, but you can also use an anonymous initialization block, like this:

```
public class Inventory {

    ArrayList inventory = new ArrayList();

    {   // An anonymous initialization block
        String item1 = "Sword";
        String item2 = "Potion";
        String item3 = "Shield";

        inventory.add(item1);
        inventory.add(item2);
        inventory.add(item3);
    }
}
```

If you use a block like that, it would be shared among all named constructors of the class, or it would become part of the implicitly generated constructor for the `Inventory`.

Answer (score 5):

Your "adding" statements are just "in the air":  not inside one method or constructor.

Wrap in inside one like for instance:

```
public class Inventory {

   private List inventory = new ArrayList();  //prefer interface here ;)

   public Inventory(){   //statements wrap into this constructor
      inventory.add("Sword");
      inventory.add("Potion");
      inventory.add("Shield");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Non declaring code has to be in a block statement like the main method.
If you would like to run the code e.g. in Eclipse with a debugger with right mouse click on the class and choosing `Debug as`/`Java Application` you could do it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Inventory {

private List<String> inventoryItems = new ArrayList<String>();

public Inventory(){
    String item1 = "Sword";
    String item2 = "Potion";
    String item3 = "Shield";

    inventoryItems.add(item1);
    inventoryItems.add(item2);
    inventoryItems.add(item3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Inventory theInventory = new Inventory();
}

}
```

This way you can set a break point at the left border of the Eclipse editing area and step through the code.

Edit: As it looks to me like Adam experiments with the code I provided a solution that makes experimenting easier.

Comment: ArrayList inventory is a private variable.

Comment: Thats correct. As it's accessed from the same class it is a visible.

Comment: But isn't it a bad class design?

Comment: Making the array list more visible than it had to be was bad design. I made it private now, moved the initialization code to the constructor, added the type for the inventory items in angle brackets and renamed the inventory items ArrayList to `inventoryItems`.

Answer (score 2):

A more general answer would be that the class body is about declarations, not statements. There is special provision for statements occurring in class body, but they have to be marked explicitly as either class initializers or instance initializers.
As the assignments are statements and statements are allowed only inside blocks of code(methods, constructors, static initializers, etc.).
So you can do as below,

```
public class Inventory {

ArrayList inventory = new ArrayList();

String item1 = null;
String item2 = null;
String item3 = null;

//initializer block
{
item1="Sword";
item2="Potion";
item3="Shield";

inventory.add(item1);
inventory.add(item2);
inventory.add(item3);
}
```